# Storing the Manager Password of Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am setting up the AD(LDAP) in spring; I have seen examples of storing the manager's(admin) password of the LDAP server in the properties file so that LDAPContextSource can be instantiated during the start up; For AD, I am kind of scared/feared of storing the manager's (admin) password in the properties; I can think of storing the password in the system's DB; but can anyone tell me the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you put it you will have the same problem. You can put it into the database but then you will probably want to encrypt it, so then you have the problem of where to store the key, and on and on. I wouldn't look beyond putting it into the applications configuration (*not* source code, e.g. a .properties file). Physical security of the server is the real answer here.

Comment: May I know what do you mean by the physical security of the server?